# How do I pull a specific sentence within a paragraph in a json on my react app?

Tags: javascript, html, json, reactjs

I want to pull a specific sentence in a paragraph within a Json on my react app. for example -

```
groupinfo: this is the groups info
errorInfo: "imagine this is a long paragraph within a Json file, and i want to display/pull just a small part of it. so for instance i want just (long paragraph) and I want to know how to just pull that one part of the paragraph"
```

I want to use this small part of the paragraph to complete a weblink, so the small sentence it uses needs to be variable and be determined base upon the artifactID within the json.

so what if this were to work it would pull just that small part of the paragraph within the Json and would display it as a link to a website. If i need to do more explaining let me know.

Answer (score -1):

what if you get it with substring?

```
const myStr = 'Alligator';

const myNewStr = myStr.substring(0, 3);

console.log(myNewStr); // All
```